# Wifi hardware is not found

Tags: networking, wireless

I have a dell inspiron 13 7000 thats running xubuntu 14.04. When I press the network button in the corner, i see the message "No network devices found" I am certain this is not a hardware switch because this comupter has none, and i would be getting a message saying it was disabled by a hardware switch. My wifi hardware is "Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 59)."

Interestingly, when i was installing grub with the boot repair disk distro, the wifi worked fine. I beleive that boot repair disk is based on ubuntu but in am not sure.

Anyway, what should i do to get my wifi working?

thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of these terminal commands: `uname -r` and also: `dmesg | grep iwl`. Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: when i type uname -r i get: "3.13.0-63-generic" when i type dmesg | grep iwl I get: [    9.958594] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: irq 62 for MSI/MSI-X
[    9.958817] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
[    9.958819] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Falling back to user helper
[    9.959165] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
[    9.959168] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Falling back to user helper
[    9.959427] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: request for firmware file 'iwlwifi-7265-7.ucode' failed.
[    9.959477] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: no suitable firmware found!

Comment: wait, my computer does have a network switch, but when i press it, it toggles bluetooth

Comment: May I also see: `modinfo iwlwifi | grep 7265` and also: `ls /lib/firmware | grep 7265`. Thanks.

Comment: when i type modinfo iwlwifi | grep 7265 i get: firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-7.ucode

Comment: i get no output from the second command

Comment: The wifi is working after a dist-upgrade. Thanks to evreyone who helped me on this :)

Comment: If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: http://askubuntu.com/tour

Answer (score 2):

The firmware version -7 is no longer available. I recommend that you upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04.4 which will bring a later kernel version, a newer driver version and a newer version of *linux-firmware*. In a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Reboot. Your wireless should be working.